# Format specifier inside os path join

Tags: python

I am trying to evaluate results from this ML [project](https://github.com/rddy/deeptutor), where rewards are saved into .pkl file, and then are later manipulated.
This takes reward_logs variable and creates a .pkl file successfully:

```
with open(os.path.join(data_dir, 'reward_logs.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(reward_logs, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

But then, reward_logs are read with format specifier at the end, which reads non-existent file, for example first iteration: `reward_logs.pkl.0`

```
R = np.zeros((6, len(tutor_builders), n_eps, n_reps))
for i in range(6):
  with open(os.path.join(data_dir, 'reward_logs.pkl.%d' % i), 'rb') as f:
    reward_logs = pickle.load(f)
    R[i] = reward_logs['rewards']
    print(reward_logs['env_names'], reward_logs['reward_funcs'])
```

It errors as expected at `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\data\\reward_logs.pkl.0'`

What is the purpose of the format specifier? I cant find anything related to usage of format specifiers in os.path.join function. The code is 4 years old, so I was wondering if something changed, if so, how should I rewrite this loop?

Comment: The `%d` format specifier is used to append a number from 0 to 5 to the filename. *Why* this is done we can't tell you.

Comment: That much i can tell, but it makes no sense to read a file that has numbers at end when it doesnt exist, the only created file is without numbers. The only thing that I can think of is that the usage was changed in last 4 years.